# Client IP address using emulator

Tags: sockets, client

I am currently writing this code for my client and server,

and I want to test it out using my emulator, but I'm stuck.

is this the correct IP address that I should be using?

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 6000);
```

If i want to use my phone to test this out, what ip address should i be using?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send messages between server/client, here is a sample code that i have made before.

please refer to the code below and feel free to comment!

also, that is the correct ip address to use when using emulator for simulation.

in addition, don't forget to change your permission to "android.permission.INTERNET" in your manifesto.

```
=================================myClient==================================

    package com.example.myclient;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        /** Manifest --> uses permission --> "android.permission.INTERNET" */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    class MyThread extends Thread {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            super.run();
                            Log.d("client", "thread is running...");
                            String str = "Do you want to eat hamburger?";
                            Socket socket;
                            try {
                                socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 6000);
                                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket
                                        .getOutputStream());
                                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                                        socket.getInputStream());
                                out.writeObject(str);
                                String rcv = (String) in.readObject();
                                Log.d("client", "Server :" + rcv);
                                out.close();
                                in.close();
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MyThread t = new MyThread();
                    t.start();

                }
            });

        }

    }



============================MyServer========================================

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6000);
        System.out.println("waiting.....");
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("a client has connected...");
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

            String str = (String) objIn.readObject();
            System.out.println("client : " + str);
            objOut.writeObject("No, I'm on a diet!!!");

            objIn.close();
            objOut.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2 will be the correct IP you are using emulator. 127.0.0.1 will be the IP if you are developing on the machine(client and server on same machine). As you said you want to test it in your mobile run the following code and you will get your IP(it will also work if you are on computer):

```
public class net
{
  net() throws UnknownHostException
 {
   InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   System.out.println(ia);

   ia=InetAddress.getByName("local host");
   System.out.println(ia);
 }
 public static void main(String args[])throws UnknownHostException
    {
   net a=new net();
    }
  }
```